# Is there a way to keep ssh authentication open for several scp commands?

Tags: ssh, authentication

I need to copy several small files from a remote machine to a local one. I need to do this several times a day. Currently, I use a script that use scp to copy the files. However, this is slow as every time, I need to authenticate. Is there a way, beside mounting, to do one authentication and keep it alive until I finish the copy?

Comment: why not copy the individual files into a folder, zip and then send it across in one go?

Comment: They are scatter over several folders on a computation cluster which I don't wish to run script on. I guess that this is an option con consider though.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the *ControlMaster* feature of SSH. For this purpose I placed a global Option:

```
Host *
    ControlPath ~<user>/.ssh/ctrl-%r-%h-%p
```

In my .ssh/config. Of course you must replace `<user>` accordingly by your login name.

Whenever I want to setup an initial master connection I add '-M':

```
ssh -M <machine>
```

This creates a control socket with a filename specified above. Any subsequent call to ssh/scp targeting that `<machine>` will reuse the existing master connection. Dramatically speeding up the connection process because no further authentication is needed for the time the control (==master) connection exists. As a pleasant side effect you don't need to re-enter your pass-phrase once you give it for establishing the master connect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ssh-add to add private keys to your ssh authentication agent.  See

```
man ssh-add
```

and

```
man ssh-agent
```